# Не отображается изображение в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, background

Здравствуйте. Подключила bootstrap, указала фоновое изображение, но оно почему-то не отображается. Вот что прописано в css:

```
.bg {
background: url(../img/bg_0.jpg); 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}

И html:

```
<body>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="bg">
  <!-- Navigation begining -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <img src="img/smart_logo.png" alt="logo" width="200" class="smartLogo">
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navMenu">
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li style="margin-right: 50px;"><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
            <li class="lang"><a href="#"> <img src="img/lang.png" alt="language" width="20"> ENG</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: А Вы фоновое изображение какому элементу задаёте?

Comment: прошу извинить, не корректно отформатировала код. теперь все видно - классу bg.

Comment: Потому что там всё на float'ах?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да нет вроде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По представленному коду видно, что ваш div с картинкой находится под navbar.

Класс `.navbar-default` и `.navbar-inverse` имеют свойства `background-color` и `border-color`. Вот они как раз перекрывают ваш `div` со свойством `background`.

Есть несколько решений:

1. Переопределите класс `.navbar-default` и `.navbar-inverse`
2. Перенесите ваш `div` с классом `bg` во внутрь элемента `nav` с классом `.navbar`
3. Примените ваш класс `bg` к элементу `nav` с классом `.navbar`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прописать полный путь до изображения в css. Просто у вас с путями проблема.

Comment: Нет, это точно не пути, так как я искала причину ошибки самостоятельно. Более того, никаких ошибок при отладке не выявляется.

Comment: Откройте через crome исходный код страницы, найдите где у вас должна быть фоновая картинка и посмотрите корректно ли она открывается на новой вкладке. У вас стили вообще в блоке head подключены? Так как в приведенном вами коде этого не видно.

Comment: Здесь в коде не видно, но они подключены верно, у меня не получается почему-то разместить тут код полностью. Исходный код страницы показывает ее верно, но сама страница выглядит просто белой.

Comment: Закрывающие теги </div> все на месте?

Comment: да, все до последнего, перепроверила еще раз.

Comment: Просто в вашем примере их 4 , а открывающих 5

Comment: пятый не отобразился почему-то, в исходнике их 5, как и должно быть. Может ли быть такое, что bootstrap просто проигнорировал свойства, так как были указаны свойства с более высоким приоритетом?

Comment: Посмотрите статью https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/211032/ здесь думаю есть то что вам нужно. Просто нет компьютера под рукой для проверки вашего кода.

Comment: ок, спасибо. попробую Jumbotron'ом решить проблему

Answer (score 0):

Вам в CSS нужно просто заменить `.bg` на `nav`